# How to combine insert query and update query with different tables into single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to combine this query into single query?

```
INSERT INTO transactions (quantity) VALUES (2);
UPDATE items SET stock = 5 WHERE id = 1;
```

thank you.

Comment: Well, you probably might add the `INSERT` into a CTE and then `SELECT` from that CTE in the `UPDATE` or something similar. Technically that would be one statement but is no easier to read or write. And your two statements aren't related to each other as it seems. So the question is what you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer? You can't. There is no SQL command that allows you to insert into one table and simultaneously update another table.

You can, however, make them part of the same *transaction* so that they both happen, or both don't happen, so you don't end up in a situation where the INSERT succeeded but the UPDATE failed

Answer (score 0):

You can update two tables at the same time but updating one and inserting other table in one query is not possible. But the loop hole would the use of procedures with start transaction like @Caius Jard mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with i as (
    INSERT INTO transactions (quantity)
        VALUES (2)
        RETURNING *
    )
UPDATE items
SET stock = 5
WHERE id = 1;
```

The `returning` clause would actually let you use values from the `insert` in the `update`.  This construct is a big convenience in Postgres.